# get added file in directory TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Simple question.

I need to get a file that has been added to a directory by another developer, but do not want to update any of the other files in the directory. How can I only update that 1 file when I don't have it currently? commit + update is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the file in the repo browser, right-click, and choose "Copy to working copy".

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your working copy folder, choose "Check for modifications". In that dialog, click on the button "check repository".

Now the added file is shown in the file list of the CfM dialog. Right-click on that file, choose "Update" from the context menu.

Comment: +1 - did not know that. All it does is `svn ls` and `svn up` I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

To just get the single file, you can: Right-click the containing folder, go to TortoiseSVN>RepoBrowser, find the file, right-click and Save As.

If you really needed a versioned copy of the file, you could always back up any changes, update the whole folder, then use Update to Revision on all files other than that one new file to roll them back to the desired revision... Not entirely sure what you need to achieve.

Comment: yea, but isn't that going to cause some 'already added' errors when i try to commit the file with new changes?

Comment: Added another possibility. You could also just check out a new copy of the folder, with Checkout Depth set to "Only file children", in order to edit and commit the file separately from your main working copy. Why are you unable to update the other files?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't just a `svn up filename` work? ( assuming you have a cli client)

As per the other answer, `Copy to Working Copy` may not be what you want to do. It creates a new file and `svn add`s it to the working copy. Your wroking copy has no idea that someone has commited such a file ( until you commit that is )

Comment: A TortoiseSVN dev said "Copy to working copy copies a file from the repository or another working copy into you local working copy so that it will be added to the repository in the new location but retaining its full historical context." 
I assumed the 'full historical context' thing meant it was basically just checking out the file, but now that I think about it, you're probably right.